# NullPointerException when calling an operator

Tags: java, object, nullpointerexception, operator-keyword

I have a Fraction object that I defined in a java class. I need to be able to do math with fractions that I create. When I do math with an undefined fraction, I am required to return null. My problem is when the user doesn't know that null was returned and tries to do math with a Fraction object that is set to null.

For example.

```
Fraction f1=null;
Fraction f2=new Fraction(1, 2);
Fraction f3=f1.add(f2);
```

This will give me an error. But when I do it the other way around, there is no error.

```
Fraction f1=null;
Fraction f2=new Fraction(1, 2);
Fraction f3=f2.add(f1);
```

This wont error and will instead return null.

Why does the top example error and how do I force it to instead return null? Also, the checking if the fraction is null can not happen in my tester program, it has to happen in the Fraction class.
The add operator works just fine. I just want it to return null when the Fractions object equals null.

Comment: the top example fails because `f1` is null and you can't call a function on null. What you can do is replace your function by a static function that tests both operands

Comment: You can't. Calling a method on a null reference is a bug, and will always lead to a NPE.

Comment: You want the fraction f3 to return null in second example?

Comment: @Scitech The second example already returns null. Which is correct. I want the the first example to return null.

Comment: That's not gonna happen.

Comment: Ok, use a static method. This eliminates the object creation.

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do is not possible because you cannot call a method on a `null` object. Trying it will always yield and exception. However, if this is really important for you, you could change the API to a static method with two parameters:

```
public static Fraction add(Fraction f1, Fraction f2)
```

Now you can return `null` in case one of the parameters is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Calling a method on a `null` object, will always end with a `NullPointerException`.